# Is there a way to receive builds list from Jenkins from a specific number?

Tags: jenkins

I'm using the following API to receive a list of builds per a job:
http://example.jenkins.com/job/someJob/api/json/parameters?pretty=true&tree=builds[number,result,building,actions[parameters[*]]]

The response is a JSON string with the list of all of the builds of someJob.
is there a way to get the list starting from a specific build_number?

Answer (score 1):

For array-type properties, a range specifier is supported. For example, tree=jobs[name]{0,10} would retrieve the name of the first 10 jobs. The range specifier has the following variants:

```
{M,N}: From the M-th element (inclusive) to the N-th element (exclusive).
{M,}: From the M-th element (inclusive) to the end.
{,N}: From the first element (inclusive) to the N-th element (exclusive). The same as {0,N}.
{N}: Just retrieve the N-th element. The same as {N,N+1}.
```

[above is gracefully <strike>stolen</strike> borrowed from built-in Jenkins documentation at ${JENKINS_URL}/api ]

What you want to achieve can be done this way:

for M in {10,20,30}:
Open browser link( [http://example.jenkins.com/job/someJob/api/json/parameters?pretty=true&tree=builds[number,result,building,actions[parameters[*]]]{M,}](http://example.jenkins.com/job/someJob/api/json/parameters?pretty=true&tree=builds[number,result,building,actions[parameters[*]]]%7BM,%7D) )

Note that build_number has little to do with this query. It'll count the existing build logs, so if you have some kind of log rotation mechanism there - you can't count on build_number.

Comment: Sorry, this is not wat I requested. my interest is specific with a build number.
The number of builds is getting changed and I want to receive all the builds from a specific number, for example:
There are 200 builds the smallest is 1500 and the larger is 1700. I need to get all of the builds from build 1658.

Comment: Your question asks exactly what I answered though. Query { (total_builds_currently present - latest_build_number + desired_build_number ),}

Comment: keep in mind that I'm looking for one call to get this data, this means that I don't have the numbers 1500, 1700, 200 at hand, only 1658. Do you still think that it can be accomplish with your answer?

Comment: First, edit your question to reflect what are really asking. Otherwise it's unlikely that you'll get an answer. Second: are you limited to one line of code to get this data? Otherwise - what stops you from getting needed numbers in of numerous possible ways?

Comment: I edit the Q so it will be clearer.
I'm using an observer DP, and I would like to get in one call to Jenkins, a list of all relevant builds without the need to analyze unnecessary info.